# How to create and append to a gz file without decompressing?

Tags: c++, macos, unix, gzip

I have an enormous input file, terabytes in size (it is gzipped (.gz)).

I need to read each line individually, and decide whether to add it to a new file.

The output file is also expected to be terabytes in size, but smaller since I won't add all the files.

Is there a way to do this in C++, using the standard libraries ? I don't want to use boost. Is that possible ?

Comment: Have you checked if it's technically possible (file-format wise) to append to a gzip file?  If it's not, this is not a programming issue.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. I know you can read from it without decompressing the file (for e.g.: in terminal you can use zcat or zless), so I imagine you can also read from gzip using c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard C++ libraries do not deal with gzip format. Neither do the standard C libraries. I don't know about boost.

But you can certainly use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), which I believe comes with a C++ wrapper if the use of C is too daunting.

It's not generally a good idea to append to a gzipped file, by the way, although it is theoretically possible. But you lose a lot of compression because the algorithm needs to be reset and thereby loses context. However, you can open a compressed stream and write to it, so you don't need to write the uncompressed file to disk. I think that's all you need for this query.

Comment: What do you mean by compressed stream ? What kind of compression ?

Comment: @john: gzip compression. A compressed stream is a stream (in the sense of io stream) which compresses as it output and/or decompresses as it inputs, so that the compressed version is on disk and the uncompressed version is in memory. For the C interface, see http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip. A C++ interface is in boost, but you have indicated that you don't want to use that.